# Making a view for a program for windows

Tags: model-view-controller, kotlin, interface

I need some help on creating the view part of my program. 
I started working in Kotlin because I would like to get familiar with it but now I face the problem that I have no experience on creating a view, an interface for my program.

Where is a good place to start on making good interfaces with Kotlin? 
I work with intellIJ IDE

Apologies if my English is not that great. 
Ask me if you have any questions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert programmer but in Java I used JavaFX to make interfaces. You can use it the same way in kotlin, but I heard TornadoFX was a good idea. I think there are many JavaFX tutorials, so it is not very complicated.